# Is "Ubuntu for Phones" as powerful as Ubuntu for PC's?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I recently got a quad-core smartphone, and I am wanting to squeeze out every bit of performance and productivity out of it. I have been looking around and can't seem to find a straight answer on some questions I have.

First off, is Ubuntu for Phones actually a full fledged distribution or is is stripped down to be more of a phone-like OS? Would I be able to download programs that are available for linux? Be able to run .deb packages? Open a Terminal?

And lastly, is there a way to install the latest distro of Ubuntu onto my mobile device? In replacement of Android (for experimental purposes)? The only answers I can find is to VNC into it on your phone, but it is still too slow and laggy. I understand one would have to pull the drivers from one owns device but surely this is possible?

Thank you for your time in reading this and I am very interested in hearing your thoughts or information leading me to my answers!

Comment: *First off, is Ubuntu for Phones actually a full fledged distribution or is is stripped down to be more of a phone-like OS?* - It's a Mobile OS just like Android, iOS or Windows Phone. *And lastly, is there a way to install the latest distro of Ubuntu onto my mobile device? In replacement of Android (for experimental purposes)?* - Officially only the Nexus 7 supports this, although there are other devices that are capable of it, namely the ASUS Transformer.

Comment: @UriHerrera Correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't that suffice as an answer?

Comment: @TheLordofTime Anything can be an answer but I didn't put it as one because I'm not explaining or citing official sources or expanding on the subject I'm just commenting on what he said.

Answer (score 1):

It's too early to provide a fully satisfying answer as Ubuntu Touch has only started as a Developer Preview yet.

The idea is that the final Ubuntu Touch will allow you to connect the device (should be a powerful one) via docking station to monitor and keyboard/mouse and can be used as a normal workstation.

There are already devices which are powerful enough and Ubuntu with all components is already fully available for arm machines.

It will be exciting to find out if it's powerful enough but we will have to wait for at least half a year.

The only thing you can see right now is the new mobile version of unity and you can connect to your Ubuntu Touch via adb or ssh and you can run all possible command line programs.

Comment: Thanks for all the prompt responses! I think I will give the developer preview a shot and try to get it working on my device. I have always been a big supporter of the Ubuntu distro of linux operating systems and am eager to see how the developers have come along on their version of a mobile operating system. I don't thing I will be disappointed regardless!